# How I connect Sonos with Flutter

Tags: flutter, just-audio, sonos

I've developed a music app through Flutter. I want to listen to the songs on sonos, but I can't find any packages for sonos on the internet.

How can I use Flutter to play songs via sonos, I use just_audio for music play.

What packages can be used to do this?

Or do you give an example of projects for flutter ?

Comment: There is actually a ton of information about the SONOS API here :
https://devdocs.sonos.com/docs/control, if this works, let me know and I will type up a full answer.